# How to change the color of SVG image in fabric js?

Tags: php, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have an SVG image object(i.e car.svg) in my Canvas , is that possible to change the color of that SVG image object. how to do that in fabric js?

like this website do : [birds color change](http://www.wallsneedlove.com/origami-bird-wall-decals/#.UjAbPMZHKBo)

And if is possible to change image color like this website do :[http://dalidecals.com/Classic-Family-Name-Personalized-Monogram-Wall-Decals-Stickers-Custom.html](http://www.easel.ly)
.Any idea how to do this in fabric js.

Comment: You'll need to set `fill` value of an object if you're dealing with `fabric.Path`. Or `fill` value of all child objects if you're dealing with `fabric.PathGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

lately i used one of the fabric js filters for changing colore if t-shirt or mug and ... ,named **Blend Color** and it worked very well.
but as i tried it doesn't worked by svg images , i used it for png and jpg...
here is my code in javascript:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(require("../../assets/mockup/100.png"), (img) => {
  canvas.add(img);
  img.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
  img.scaleToHeight(canvas.getHeight()); var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
    color: newColor,
    mode: "multiply",
  });
  this.$store.state.mockup.currentImg.filters = [];
  this.$store.state.mockup.currentImg.filters.push(filter);
  this.$store.state.mockup.currentImg.applyFilters();
  this.$store.state.mockup.canvas.renderAll();
```

here is reference in the fabric js library :

[Class: BlendColor](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.filters.fabric.Image.filter.BlendColor.html)